# Understanding how higher order functions work in C

Tags: c, function-pointers, higher-order-functions

So usually I would declare any function pointer like this:

```
typedef size_t (*hash_function)(const int *);
```

and then later use it in another function

```
HashTable *hash_table_create(const hash_function hash)
```

so for any function which fulfills the hash_function definition like

```
size_t hash_modulo(const int *parameters)
size_t hash_universal(const int *parameters)
...
```

I can use them as a parameter

```
hash_table_create(hash_modulo)
```

**The problem is**: My IDE (Clion) complains that the parameters in this case do not match (the code works tho). Specifically it doesn't seem to accept passing `hash_function` as a parameter type, but will accept if I use `size_t (*hash_function)(const int *)` instead. What am I missing here?

Is my code right and my IDE wrong or vice versa?

Thanks in advance!

Edit 1: The exact error message is: `Types 'hash_function' and size_t(const int *)' are not compatible`

Edit 2: This seems to be a Clion [Bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5417)

Comment: I suppose you might try defining a function instead of a pointer type as a possible workaround, e.g. `typedef size_t hash_function_t(const int *);` and `HashTable *hash_table_create(hash_function_t *hash);` (and perhaps `extern hash_function_t hash_modulo, hash_universal;`.)

Comment: This works fine in GCC. And I don't see any reason thy it shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

CLion seems to have a bug (possibly). The function names are of the type `size_t(const int *)`. Now, since functions are implicitly convertible to function pointers, your code is perfectly valid C.

The CLion syntax checker probably doesn't take implicit conversions into account. If you obtain a function pointer explicitly from the function name the error should go away:

```
hash_table_create(&hash_modulo); // Note the ampersand
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you `typedef` the function as `const`

```
HashTable *hash_table_create(const hash_function hash)
```

and the other functions you want to put in as `parameters` aren't declared `const`

```
size_t hash_modulo(const int *parameters)
size_t hash_universal(const int *parameters)
```

Edit:

This works fine in CodeBlocks

Change this:

```
size_t hash_modulo(const int *parameters)
size_t hash_universal(const int *parameters)
```

into this:

```
hash_function hash_modulo;
hash_function hash_universal;
```

and then this work fine:

```
hash_table_create(hash_modulo);
hash_table_create(hash_universal);
```

Explanation in the comment below.

Comment: It gets even weirder... when I remove the const from `hash_table_create` it won't even be able to resolve the variable hash. O.o

Comment: I just tried it in codeeblocks, I can only compile it, when I change the declaration from `size_t hash_modulo(const int *parameters)` to `hash_function hash_modulo;`. Otherwise in get the error message `main.cpp|276|error: invalid conversion from 'std::size_t* (*)(const size_t*) {aka unsigned int* (*)(const unsigned int*)}' to 'hash_function {aka unsigned int (*)(const unsigned int*)}' [-fpermissive]|`

Comment: Okay weird so I guess I have apointer wrong here or I need to dereference

Comment: From my understanding, the compiler checks, if the functionpointer given as paramter is really declared as the one from the typedef, not just if it has the same parameter and returntype.